# How to get all the link in page using selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have tried the code given below but every time i run the code,there is some links added to missing. I want to get all the links in the page in a list,so that i can go to any link that i want using slicing.

```
links = []
eles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")

for elem in eles:#
    url = elem.get_attribute('href')
    print(url)
    links.append(url)
```

is there any way to get all the elements without missing any.

Comment: This won't return dynamic links. Simple solution is to add `time.sleep(10)` before scraping links

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the links reside inside the frames.
Search for the frames in your website using inspect.
so you need to switch the frame first

```
browser.switch_to.frame("x1")
links = []
eles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")

for elem in eles:#
    url = elem.get_attribute('href')
    print(url)
    links.append(url)
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```